# Using Packages without the F# Project Structure

Tags: f#, package

Is there any way to just install a package in my system and have any `.fs` file be able to reference it?
Is it possible to use F# Packages without following the Project Structure?
All FSharp uses of external packages I have seen either make use of NuGet (for proper *big* projects) or reference a downloaded dll (for F# `.fsx` scripts).

I'm looking to make use of the compiler and generate an executable.

**My use case is the following:**

I have a very simple command line script that does not justify having a complex project structure with a bunch of project, paket and config files. All I really need is to compile a single FSharp file and produce an `.exe`.

Now, this script requires doing some HTTP requests, retrieving a JSON response, and transform that data - I believe FSharp.Data is the perfect tool for the job but I have been unable to find out how integrate it with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a supported way to exactly what you need until this language suggestion is implemented https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/master/tooling/FST-1027-fsi-references.md

If you need only FSharp.Data and don't care about editor tooling and lib versioning much, you can download the .dll manually, use from your file (let's call it `app.fs`) and then with F# tools installed you can compile it with something like `fsc.exe -r:<path-to-FSharp.Data.dll> -o app.exe --standalone --target:exe app.fs` (I haven't tried this particular set of options, but you can check [fsc docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options))

---

The project system isn't that complex and heavyweight though, especially if you can use .NET Core SDK with its command-line interface.

If you run `dotnet new console -lang=F#`, the complete project file looks like this

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and depending on your tooling you can just add `<PackageReference Include="FSharp.Data" Version="3.0.0" />` to the `<ItemGroup>` and after you `dotnet publish`, you have your app ready.

Comment: I second the suggestion that the project system isn't that heavyweight in practice, especially because there are templates you can clone and just tweak a couple of things. For example, if you have the .Net Core SDK, you can use the [MiniScaffold template](https://github.com/TheAngryByrd/MiniScaffold/): run `dotnet new -i MiniScaffold` and then `dotnet new mini-scaffold -lang F# -n MyProject -ou console`. Then you'll have a complete project already set up for you, and you just need to add FSharp.Data to `paket.dependencies` and re-run `paket install`, then run `./build.sh` or `build.cmd`.

Comment: If you don't have .Net Core, then you can similarly clone https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold, edit `paket.dependencies`, run `paket install` and then `./build.sh` or `build.cmd`. Either way — .Net Core or .Net Framework — there's a template to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can always invoke the compiler directly to generate your executable:

```
Fsc.exe
"..\projects\modules\src\Calculate primes.fs"
-o:"..\projects\modules\bin\Calculate primes.exe"
--debug:full
--define:DEBUG
--define:TRACE
--target:winexe
-g
--warn:3
--warnaserror:76
--vserrors
--utf8output
--fullpaths
--flaterrors
--subsystemversion:6.00
--highentropyva+
--optimize-
--tailcalls-
-I:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1"
-I:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades"
```

Create a batch file and put it all in one line.
Add the libraries you need like this:

```
-r:"..\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net45\FSharp.Data.dll"
```

After compilation you may need to copy all dlls used in the same directory as the executable and it helps to have a `<program>.exe.config` file.